# part-r-00000 no such file or directory

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run the example AggregateWordCount but I get this error, when I use this code to run Wordcount everything works fine.

```
!/bin/bash
# test the hadoop cluster by running wordcount

# create input files
mkdir input
echo "Hello World" >input/file2.txt
echo "Hello Hadoop" >input/file1.txt

# create input directory on HDFS
hadoop fs -mkdir -p input
put input files to HDFS
hdfs dfs -put ./input/* input

# run wordcount
#hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/sources/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.7-sources.jar org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount input output

hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/sources/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.7-sources.jar org.apache.hadoop.examples.AggregateWordCount input output

# print the input files
echo -e "\ninput file1.txt:"
hdfs dfs -cat input/file1.txt
echo -e "\ninput file2.txt:"
hdfs dfs -cat input/file2.txt

# print the output of wordcount
echo -e "\nwordcount output:"
hdfs dfs -cat output/part-r-00000
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you a recursive find on hdfs with the below command where you wrote the file with 
`output/part-r-00000`

```
hadoop fs -ls -R /user/your_directory grep -i "output/part-r-00000"
```

should recursively list directories .

Adjust your code or script to point to that.

Comment: if you are okay please care to accept [the answer as owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/369717) and [vote-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/369717)